How to subscribe for the Security tab on github
I'd like to create an RSS feed (or anything similar) for the following page: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/security
My goal would be to subscribe somehow for the keycloak-related security incidents, and get a post in my RSS reader / get notified by an email / etc when a new entry is created.
Any way to do that?
Thanks for the help,

If the repository publishes security advisories the easiest way would be to create a custom watch for security alerts
Steps would be
Navigate to Repository > Watch > Custom > Security Alerts

Getting an email can be tricky as a few people have reported that they don't receive emails if only subscribed to Security Alerts. The work around for it seems to be subscribing to All Activity for the time being
